# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property of 'stations' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, heroku

I have a get request on my frontend code.

```
  fetch('/usershop', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res=> res.json())
  .then(res=> {
        var obj = {}
//error found here
        res.map(item=> {
          obj[item["_id"]]={stations: item.locations.stations, position: item.locations.position, yourshopname: item.locations.yourshopname, items: item.items }}
        )
        this.setState({stations: obj})
      })
```

.catch(err=> console.log(err))
      }

When I console.log  "res" after my final .then, I get a array of objects. Below is an example of one of the objects. In other words, below is an item of res. They all have locations

```
0:
accepts:[]
firstname: "jon"
items:[{…}]
lastname:"lee"
locations:{position: Array(2), _id: "3lkj2jt390fgs90", stations: 
"21lkjfoadf0j204j2", yourshopname: "jshop", __v: 0}
messages:[]
password:"kajdflka"
username:"alkklagf"
__v:2
_id:"lkjgaklfjgalkfdjglkaj"
__proto__:Object
```

But when I try to map it over, it's giving me the error: Cannot read property of 'stations' of undefined.

When I tried console.logging item._id and so on, it all worked out.

**When did I start getting the error**: 
when I was just running on localhost, I had /build in my gitignore file. It all worked fine. But I wanted to put it on heroku cloud. So I took out /build from gitignore file and ran npm run build. As soon as I did that, this stopped working even when i just run it on my localhost.

Please help! FYI, I need to get each object into that format because I am using Mapbox API gl react api. 
https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl

Comment: .catch(err => console.log(err))  you could do this so it prints the error in the console instead of breaking the app

Comment: that is the first item of 'res', but what if another item doesn't have locations? are you sure all have .locations?

Comment: also comment that line ...obj[] = ... to be sure that line has the problem, because you also have 'stations' as a state var, so maybe the error is in another place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an empty object to map over before you do the fetch request. (on mount of your component for example, or in the constructor)

Otherwise the map function tries to map on an undefined obejct since the fetch-call is asynchronous.